# Subview will not be removed from superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to delete a group of subviews depending on which row is selected, however when the method is called, only the first if statement works as it should, the if(firstRowSelected)

The subviews are tagged from 10 and up in the first row, 50 and up in the second, and 100 and up in the third. I can´t understand what is wrong, as the code within the if bodies are identical except some variables.

```
- (void) resetLane{
    if (firstRowSelected) {
        for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
            if (subview.tag >= 10 && subview.tag < 50) {
                currentCardL1 = 10;
                sipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sips: %d", sipCount];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:.4
                                  delay:.1
                                options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                             animations:^{
                                 animationPlaying = YES;
                                 CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 180, 71, 96);
                                 subview.frame = f;

                             }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                                 [subview removeFromSuperview];
                                 sipCount += 1;
                                 cDisplayedL1 = 0;

                             }];
            }
        }
        [self dealNewCard];

    }else if (secondRowSelected) {
        for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
            if (subview.tag >= 50 && subview.tag < 100) {
                currentCardL2 = 10;
                sipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sips: %d", sipCount];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:.4
                                      delay:.1
                                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                 animations:^{
                                     animationPlaying = YES;
                                     CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 180, 71, 96);
                                     subview.frame = f;

                                 }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                                     [subview removeFromSuperview];
                                     sipCount += 1;
                                     cDisplayedL2 = 0;
                                 }];
            }
        }
        [self dealNewCard];

    }else if (thirdRowSelected) {
        for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
            if (subview.tag >= 100 && subview.tag < 150) {
                NSLog(@"imgage with tag %ld removed", (long)subview.tag);
                currentCardL3 = 100;
                sipCount += 1;
                sipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sips: %d", sipCount];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:.4
                                      delay:.1
                                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                 animations:^{
                                     animationPlaying = YES;
                                     CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 180, 71, 96);
                                     subview.frame = f;

                                 }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                                     [subview removeFromSuperview];
                                     cDisplayedL3 = 0;
                                 }];
            }
        }

        [self dealNewCard];
    }
}
```

Comment: does it enter the `firstRowSelected` statement every time?

Comment: Clarify the problem. When you say only the first if works as it should, do you mean that the others are entered but don't work properly or do you mean only the first is ever entered? If the former, please clarify how they are not working.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention the actual issue. The first "if" removes subviews with tags 10,11,12,13,14 and so on, however the second and third "if" only removes the subview with tag 50(secondRowSelected and 100(thirdRowSelected). 

The subviews with tags between 50 and 100, and 100 and 150 are not removed.